# why I can't create one layer for too or more shapes using vue-konva?

Tags: vue.js, geometry, layer, stage, vue-konva

I have a problem with vue-konva, I can't create too many shapes in the same layer
for example :

```
<template>
    <v-stage :config = "stage">
        <v-layer>
            <v-circle :config = "circle1"
            />
        </v-layer>
        <v-layer>
            <v-circle :config = "circle2"
            />
        </v-layer>
    </v-stage>
</template>
```

in the result i got the first shape and errors :

```
vue.common.dev.js:630 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: parentKonvaNode.add is not a function"
found in
---> <VArrow>
       <VCircle>... (1 recursive calls)
         <VLayer>
           <Edge>
             <VStage>
               <Anonymous>
                 <Root>
```

Comment: Can you make a demo?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `layer` component in `vue-konva`. You have to use `v-layer`:

```html
<v-stage :config = "stage">
        <v-layer>
            <v-circle :config = "{radius: 10, fill: 'blue'}"/>
        </v-layer>
        <v-layer>
            <v-circle :config = "{radius: 10, fill: 'blue'}"/>
        </v-layer>
</v-stage>
```

Comment: it was a mistake when i rewrote it here, sorry.
I used v-layer and it didn't get the expected result it only shows the first shape and get errors

Comment: Can you make a demo? I tried this and it works https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-konva-many-layers-5prkq

Comment: in sandbox it's working fine, but in VScode i get errors. this is the demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-konva-many-layers-0z12u?file=/src/App.vue
when i tried debugging, i found that tags should be closed like this :
<v-circle>....</v-circle>
not like this : <v-circle/>

Answer (score 0):

yes my bad it was v-layer it was a mistake when i rewrote it here, sorry.
I used v-layer and it didn't get the expected result it only shows the first shape and get errors.